# Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `emailExists` was not specified in `SignUp`

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

Got these warnings:

> Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `emailExists` was not specified in `SignUp`
>
> Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `onEmailChange` was not specified in `SignUp`

*emailExists prop* and *onEmailChange prop* are not specified in *components/SignUp.js*. I guess *mapStateToProps* and *mapDispatchToProps* passed into *connect()* in *containers/SignUp.js* is not injecting the *props* into *components/SignUp.js* due to some misconfiguration.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import donrollApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/LoginApp'
import Login from './components/Login'
import SignUp from './components/SignUp'

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()

let store = createStore(donrollApp, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware))
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
                <Route path="signup" component={SignUp}/>
                <Route path="*" component={Login}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

containers/SignUp.js:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import SignUp from '../components/SignUp'
import { fetchEmailExists } from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        emailExists: state.SignUp.emailExists
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onEmailChange: (email) => {
            dispatch(fetchEmailExists(email))
        }
    }
}

const SignUpContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SignUp)

export default SignUpContainer
```

reducers/SignUp.js:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'

const SignUp = (state={emailExists:false, isCheckingEmail: false}, action) => {
    let newState = Immutable.Record(state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHECK_EMAIL_EXISTS_REQUEST':
            return (new newState({isCheckingEmail:true})).toJS();
        case 'CHECK_EMAIL_EXISTS_RESPONSE':
            return (new newState({emailExists: action.emailExists})).toJS();
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default SignUp
```

reducers/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import SignUp from './SignUp'
import {  routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

const donrollApp = combineReducers({
    SignUp,
    routing: routerReducer
})

export default donrollApp
```

components/SignUp.js:

```
import React, { PropTypes }  from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router'

const SignUp = ({emailExists, onEmailChange}) => {
    let signupData = {
        firstname:{},
        lastname:{},
        email:{},
        username:{},
        password:{},
        confirmPassword:{}
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <h4 className="col-sm-12">Sign Up</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label htmlFor="inputFirstname3" className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Firstname</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputFirstname3" placeholder="Firstname" ref={node=>{signupData.firstname=node;}} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label htmlFor="inputLastname3" className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Lastname</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputLastname3" placeholder="Lastname" ref={node=>{signupData.lastname=node;}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={emailExists?'form-group row has-danger':'form-group row'}>
                    <label htmlFor="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="email" onBlur={e=>onEmailChange(signupData.email.value)} className="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" ref={node=>{signupData.email=node;}}/>
                        {emailExists?<div className="form-control-feedback">Shit, that email's taken. Try another?</div>:null}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label htmlFor="inputUsername3" className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Username</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputUsername3" placeholder="Username" ref={node=>{signupData.username=node;}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label htmlFor="inputPassword3" className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" ref={node=>{signupData.password=node;}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label htmlFor="inputConfirmPassword3" className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" id="inputConfirmPassword3"
                               placeholder="Confirm Password" ref={node=>{signupData.confirmPassword=node;}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <div className="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                        {" "}
                        <Link to="/">Login</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

SignUp.propTypes = {
    emailExists: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    onEmailChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default SignUp
```

Comment: you can simply write mapDispatchToProps like this. `const SignUpContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
   {fetchEmailExists: onEmailChange}
)(SignUp)`. And regarding the other prop `emailExists`, is the `mapStateToProps` throwing any error?

Comment: I tried your _connect()_ statement. It didn't solve the problem. Normally, _mapStateToProps_ doesn't throw any errors, instead the above mentioned warnings are thrown from _SignUp_ _component_. But when I change the value in _email_ _input_ _box_, then a `onEmailChange is not a function` error is thrown. Here, the _onBlur_ event is handled by calling the _onEmailChange_ function, which is not specified.

Comment: I found the problem. I imported the signup component instead of signup container and passed it directly into the render function in _index.js_. I have posted an answer with the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, I imported *components/SignUp.js* instead of *containers/SignUp.js* in *index.js*. So the line `import SignUp from './components/SignUp'` in *index.js* becomes `import SignUp from './containers/SignUp'`. Because, *containers* form a wrap around the *components* and map the *Redux states* to *React props* and map the *Redux dispatches* to *React prop callbacks* with all the *props* injected into the *components* when needed. The *containers* subscribe to *Redux store* and inject new *props* to the *components* when new subscription signals arrive and the *components* update themselves with the new *props*. The *components* invoke the *callback props* to change the data and in-turn make the *containers* to dispatch *actions*. For more details, we have the documentation [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html).